# C set 3 bits for a particular number

Tags: c, bit, bitmask

I am trying to understand masking concept and want to set bits 24,25,26 of a uint32_t number in C.

example i have

uint32_t data =0;

I am taking an input from user of uint_8 which can be only be value 3 and 4 (011,100)

I want to set the value 011 or 110 in bits 24,25,26 of the data variable without disturbing other bits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set bits 24, 25, and 26 of an integer without modifying the other bits, you can use this pattern:

```
data = (data & ~((uint32_t)7 << 24)) | ((uint32_t)(newBitValues & 7) << 24);
```

The first `&` operation clears those three bits.  Then we use another `&` operation to ensure we have a number between 0 and 7.  Then we shift it to the left by 24 bits and use `|` to put those bits into the final result.

I have some `uint32_t` casts just to ensure that this code works properly on systems where `int` has fewer than 32 bits, but you probably won't need those unless you are programming embedded systems.

Comment: I would suggest to use more parentheses : `warning: suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of '|' [-Wparentheses]`

Comment: I dislike that warning... but OK.

Comment: *dislike the warning* - you have made my evening 

Answer (score 2):

More general approach macro and function. Both are the same efficient as optimizing compilers do a really good job. Macro sets `n` bits of the `d` at position `s` to `nd`. Function has the same parameters order.

```
#define MASK(n)   ((1ULL << n) - 1)
#define SMASK(n,s) (~(MASK(n) << s))
#define NEWDATA(d,n,s) (((d) & MASK(n)) << s)
#define SETBITS(d,nd,n,s) (((d) & SMASK(n,s)) | NEWDATA(nd,n,s))

uint32_t setBits(uint32_t data, uint32_t newBitValues, unsigned nbits, unsigned startbit)
{
    uint32_t mask = (1UL << nbits) - 1;
    uint32_t smask = ~(mask << startbit);
    data = (data & smask) | ((newBitValues & mask) << startbit);
    return data;
}
```